# C# format JSON with backslash '\' in value

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have some JSON from a third party system that contains backslashes in the value.  For example:

```
string extract = @"{""key"": ""\/Date(2015-02-02)\/""}";
```

which without the c# string escaping corresponds to the string:

```
{"key": "\/Date(2015-02-02)\/"}
```

I'd like to be able to format (e.g. indent) this JSON.

Typically for formatting, I might use something like JsonConvert like so:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(extract), Formatting.Indented)
```

This doesn't quite work, as it sees the value as a date, but as it's not in the standard MS format of `\/Date(ticks)\/`, it goes to a date of 1 Jan 1970:

```
{
  "key": "1970-01-01T00:00:02.015+00:00"
}
```

Next approach is to use the serializer settings to not convert dates (I'm not bothered whether it recognises the field as a date, although it would probably be handy later on):

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
};

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(extract, settings), Formatting.Indented);
```

This appears to have treated the backslash as an escape character during the deserialization, so it is "lost" once I see the final result:

```
{
  "key": "/Date(2015-02-02)/"
}
```

Is there a way that I can format the JSON in C# (with or without JsonConvert), that will preserve the backslash in the value?

Note that the real JSON I am dealing with is (a) reasonably large, but not too large for some regex/find-replace solution, if really necessary (b) not under my control, so I can't change the format.  I'm sure the answer is already on StackOverflow, but I'm finding it difficult to find the right search terms...

Comment: in c# double backslash is used for representing backslash into a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that, in a JSON string literal, [the escaped solidus `"\/"` means exactly the same as the unescaped solidus `"/"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_sidebarb), and Json.NET parses and interprets this escaping at a very low level, namely [`JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L1020).  Thus there's no way for higher level code to detect and remember whether a string literal was formatted as `"\/Date(2015-02-02)\/"` or `"/Date(2015-02-02)/"` and later write back one or the other as appropriate.

If you are OK with *always* adding the extra escaping to strings that start with `/Date(` and end with `)/`, you can use a custom subclass of [`JsonTextWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) to do this:

```
public class DateLiteralJsonTextWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public DateLiteralJsonTextWriter(TextWriter writer) : base(writer) { }

    public override void WriteValue(string value)
    {
        const string startToken = @"/Date(";
        const string replacementStartToken = @"\/Date(";
        const string endToken = @")/";
        const string replacementEndToken = @")\/";

        if (value != null && value.StartsWith(startToken) && value.EndsWith(endToken))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Add the initial quote.
            sb.Append(QuoteChar);

            // Add the new start token.
            sb.Append(replacementStartToken);

            // Add any necessary escaping to the innards of the "/Date(.*)/" string.
            using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer) { StringEscapeHandling = this.StringEscapeHandling, Culture = this.Culture, QuoteChar = '\"' })
            {
                var content = value.Substring(startToken.Length, value.Length - startToken.Length - endToken.Length);
                jsonWriter.WriteValue(content);
            }

            // Strip the embedded quotes from the above.
            sb.Remove(replacementStartToken.Length + 1, 1);
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

            // Add the replacement end token and final quote.
            sb.Append(replacementEndToken);
            sb.Append(QuoteChar);

            // Write without any further escaping.
            WriteRawValue(sb.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            base.WriteValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then parse with [`DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm) as you are currently doing:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None };

var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
using (var jsonWriter = new DateLiteralJsonTextWriter(writer) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented})
{
    JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Serialize(jsonWriter,  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(extract, settings));
}

Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

This prints:

> ```
> {
>   "key": "\/Date(2015-02-02)\/"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
extract = extract.Replace("\\","\\\\");
```

before parsing the string?

Comment: This works, but feels messy.  To be precise, the following does the job - undoing the Replace at the end: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(extract.Replace("\\", "\\\\"), settings), Formatting.Indented).Replace("\\\\", "\\")`

Comment: Yes, it's a little messy, but, taking into accout the complexity of the input, I suspect you'll be forced to use this solution or something similar. Backslashes are sometimes hard to serialize/parse.