# JsonConvert.SerializeObject add backslashes to quotes

Tags: c#, json.net, amazon-sns, jsonconvert

I am sending a message from my C# Windows Service to Amazon Web Services SNS so that it can be received from an iOS application.

```
PublishRequest pubRequest = new PublishRequest();
pubRequest.TargetArn = arn;

pubRequest.Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myMessage, Formatting.Indented);
pubRequest.MessageStructure = "json";
```

When I use JsonConvert.SerializeObject this produces a mesage string like so:

```
{"default":"My Message.  ","APNS":{"aps":{"alert":{"title":"My Title","body":"MyBody data"},"data":{"someDataTolookAt":"blahblah"}}}}
```

BUT I need the quotes in the APNS part to be escaped like so:

```
{"default":"My Message.  ","APNS":{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"title\":\"My Title\","body\":\"MyBody data\"},\"data\":{\"someDataTolookAt\":\"blahblah\"}}}}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Write your own JSON converter. [See example here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Comment: [Also see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474609/c-sharp-format-json-with-backslash-in-value/36474971)

Comment: I'm just curious... Why would you need a serialized format like that? That's even not a valid json. Did you mean you want APNS part to be a string instead of an object?

Comment: For some reason AWS is only forwarding the default part of the message and not the APNS part.  From this example I believe that back slashes are required https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePushAPNSAPI.html

Comment: @HarryBoy if you look more carefully docs provide valid json with quotes around { and }

Comment: "APNS_SANDBOX":"{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : \"You have got email.\", \"badge\" : 9,\"sound\" :\"default\"}}"

Answer (score 2):

In fact API expects APNS serialized as string, not as json and you need to convert its value to json string.
Create custom JSON converter for this particular property.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyJsonConverter))]
someclass APNS {get;set;}
```

This converter will also do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(APNSobject)` => hence your json will have escaped string for apns object.